# image normalization and extract infomation of peak position and intensity in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to get a flatten image by normalizing my signal image by the beam profile image. The image I have is 512 by 512 unit 16 TIFF file. Here are the questions I have:

- as you can see in the beam profile image, the real beam profile is contaminated by few sharp spots, what is the best way to get rid off those spots?

[image: beam profile]

Assume I got a clean beam profile, the next thing I want to have is to locate every single spot and get the number of spots in the signal image. These spots in the signal image have point spread distribution over 3-5 by 3-5 pixel size. I am thinking using a dilation mask to do this job.

- However, since the size of the signal is around 3-5 pixel by 3-5 pixel, is the number I got in this way really represents the number of spots in the image? If not, how can I solve it?

[image: Singnal]

Finally, after normalized the signal image by the beam profile image,

- how can I extract the intensity of each bright spot?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the spots in the beam profile image, I would suggest low-pass filtering the beam profile image.  You can then subtract the low-pass filtered beam profile image from your signal image to get a flattened signal image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried Gaussian low-pass filtering the beam profile image. The code I use is ------------------                                                   h = fspecial('gaussian',[7,7],7);
image_lp = imfilter(imagefile,h,'replicate');                     -------------------                                                 but I still see a lot of sharp peaks on top of beam profile image. It will be very helpful if you can tell me how to do if specifically, thanks again :)

Comment: I don't have specific code for you, just my thoughts on how I would approach the problem.  Have you tried doing a FFT on this data, filtering in the Fourier domain, and then transforming back with an inverse FFT?  Low spatial frequencies are at the center of k-space and the spatial frequency increases as you move away from the center.  Attenuating the Fourier coefficients outside of a circle of radius r centered at the center of k-space is equivalent to low-pass filtering in the spatial domain.  The radius of the circle sets the cutoff frequency.

Comment: @ Matt: Do you have any example about the FFT? I think it will be very helpful to solve the problem here.